# ORDER BY and UNION are not working together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, union

To make it work I had to make a subquery and give them separate aliases. Can anyone help me with reason?

-- NOT WORKING--

```
SELECT * FROM topstates ORDER BY TopState DESC LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM bottomstates ORDER BY BottomState LIMIT 3;
```

-- WORKING--

```
SELECT * FROM 
-- had to make a subquery and Aliases (a and b) --
(SELECT * FROM topstates ORDER BY TopState DESC LIMIT 3) as a
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM bottomstates ORDER BY BottomState LIMIT 3) as b;
```

Comment: In the first version, there can only be one valid `ORDER BY` clause, which must apply to the entire query and must be at the end.

Comment: Conceptually ORDER BY is over the resultset ,in your first query the resultset is everything that is returned by the union.. I would dispute the notion that the second query works or is robust enough to be trustworthy even though it syntaxes and produces output for the reason just stated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is covered in the MySQL documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-order-by-limit